# IE (only) Gains Margin-Top on Hover in Slideshow? (CSS & link to project Included)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, slideshow

IE slideshow bumps down on hover.

development.legendarylion.com

Any ideas why the slideshow gains top margin on hover?

Project is at: http://development.legendarylion.com

CSS

```
    div#slideshow {
    width: 947px; height: 554px;
    overflow: scroll; /* Allows the slides to be viewed using scrollbar if Javascript isn't available */
    position: relative; z-index: 5;
}

ul#slides{margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;list-style-type:none;}
ul#nav {margin:0; padding:0;}
div#slideshow ul#nav {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative; top: 250px; z-index: 15;
}
    div#slideshow ul#nav li#prev {
        float: left; margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
div#slideshow ul#nav li#next {
    float: right; margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
div#slideshow ul#nav li a {
    display: block; width: 20px; height: 37px; text-indent: -9999px;
}
    div#slideshow ul#nav li#prev a {
        background: url(../img/prev-b.png);
    }
    div#slideshow ul#nav li#next a {
        background: url(../img/next-b.png);
    }

div#slideshow ul#slides {
    list-style: none;
}
    div#slideshow ul#slides li {
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be only in ie8 and lower. Have you tried overriding the css rules that seems to be added? For exemple

```
#slides li:hover
{
    margin-top:0px !important;
    top:0px !important;
    padding-top:0px !important;
}
```